# Access 2013 unable to add new line to form and runtime error 2105 when trying to a new record

Tags: runtime-error, ms-access-2013

I am migrating several adp files to accdb so that it can work under access 2013 but one problem is driving me nuts:
I have a form on which I **cannot see an empty line to add new data**.

- the form property **allowaddition is on**
- the recordsource of the form is an sql View to which I can add a new line directly from access (so it is not readonly)
- I am forcing the AllowAddition on the code when initializing security with me.allowadditions = true  (this used to be enough to make it work in the old adp)
- I have a button to add a new line to the form that runs on_click and gives me a runtime error on this line of code **Docmd.gotorecord , , AcNewRec**
  The runtime error is "2105 : you can't go to the specified record".
  This tells me that there is something that is still read only.
- the **SQL View has an index** as well as all the table used in it.
- I tried to replace the view in the recordset of the form by a table and still not working.

Am I missing something? What else can I do to be able to add a new record to my form (or view)?

Thank you

Comment: Can you edit existing records with the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting focus to one of the textbox controls in your form before calling the new record, something along the lines of

```
me.txtControl.SetFocus
```

The reason is, SQL Server backend allocates new records differently than Access backend, and Access does a bit of magic for you in the interface, so I've found sometimes explicitly setting focus to a text control will fix this issue.

Depending on how things are structured with your Access app, if that suggestion doesn't work, then you might need to go the extra step of programatically creating the new record (blank fields except for primary key) in SQL Server first and then refresh the Access form and then setfocus to the newly created record (e.g. either the last or first record depending on your recordsource sort order)

Comment: thanx Mike, the set focus didn't do it. I also tried to add a new record to the view or directly to the table and I am getting a runtime error 3027, cannot update, the database or object is read-only! I have testes that I can add data to the view or the table directly from access, how come is it still read-only??

Comment: I found a way to add programatically data to my view, switching between adodb and DAO and using  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(ViewName, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)  made it work. thank you